# Content script doesn't work on the popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Why `changeContentName` function isn't invoked when the extension's popup is shown?

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":"This is my first chrome addon!",
    "description": "This extension just shows a text!",
    "version":"1.0",
    "icons":{
        "128":"icon.png",
        "16":"icon.png"
        },
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon.png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html",
        "default_title":"Click here!"
    },
    "content_scripts":[{
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["JavaScript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions":[
        "activeTab",
        "history",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Awesome PopUp!</title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"/>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="1">Pasta la Pasta</a>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript.js:

```
var changeContentName = function(id, value){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    changeContentName("1", "Hello");
});
```

Comment: I think your file should be named "background.js"

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts aren't autoinserted into extension's pages like the popup page.

I don't see any need for the content script in this case. Just reference the script file in `popup.html`:

```
<head>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
```

And remove `"content_scripts"` section from manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already referenced the .js file in my popup.html as you can see in my post. I removed the content_scripts - section in my manifest but it still doesn't work (i don't see any text if i click on the extension-icon).

Comment: Any ideas what i could do next to fix the problem?

Comment: @binaryBigInt, you did it wrong. The answer shows the correct syntax.